ROS2 multithreading for sequential movement of robot arm
I currently have a ros node :
import rclpy
from rclpy.action import ActionClient
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.time import Duration
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
from std_msgs.msg import Float32, Int32, Int32MultiArray, Bool
import math
import time
import numpy
import threading

class Game(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        #Main node code 
class pauser(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_subscription(Int32, "/feedback", self.feedba, 10)
        while True :
            while self.feedba == 0 :
                #take lock and pause the main game thread 
            
    #Game pauser to allow robot arm to reach targets 
    #Current feedback system , topic /feedback ,data : 1 for idle ,0 for not idle
    


def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = Game()

    executor = rclpy.executors.MultiThreadedExecutor()
    executor.add_node(node)
    executor.spin()
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I've attempted to use the python threading library to create two separate threads but couldnt manage to figure it out, also attempted to make it into a multithreaded node but couldnt figure it out.
